# How to set email logo as it is Sales email Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I have created custom email template in which i include header but i get the by default Luma logo instead of which i upload the logo from the backend side how can i got the Uploaded logo in my custom email?

Comment: Please verify logo uploaded or not in admin?

Comment: My uploaded logo is display in sales email like new order, invoice but in my custom email template i get the Luma logo

Comment: Are you using custom header in your email template?

Comment: No i use same header as in module sales email template

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go to

> Content → Design → Configuration-> Edit(Storeview) → Transactional Emails → Logo Image